# A probabilistic algorithm (something close to Discrete logarithm)

Tags: probability, group-theory, algorithms, finite-groups

$p$ - is a prime number.
$a\in Z_p^*$ is a creator of the group $Z_p ^*$.

The definition of the *Discrete logarithm* of $c\in Z_p^*$ is: $$\log_a c=b\iff a^b=c \mod p $$

Assume we have an algorithm that calculates for us $\frac{1}{10}$ of the Discrete logarithm for given $a,p$.

Can you help find a  probabilistic algorithm for finding the Discrete logarithm of $c\in Z_p^*$. (+The exception for the amount of steps).

**Please pay attention that the question is little bit about Discrete logarithm, and much more about probability (or:  probabilistic algorithm).**

I'd like to get any help,
Thank you!

Comment: $b$ must be less then $p-1$ and non-negative?

Comment: @Exodd - of course!!